# Test server endpoints on a Kafka Streams application built with Ktor

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, ktor

I have a simple Kafka Streams application built with Ktor. The `Application.kt` looks like

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module() {
    install(Routing) {
        healthController()
    }
    val stream = createStream()
    stream.start()
}
```

where

```kotlin
fun Route.healthController() {
    get("/health") {
        call.respond("I'm alive")
    }
}
```

I would like to write unit tests to test the endpoints of my application (i.e. `/health`). I have created the following unit test

```kotlin
@Test
    fun `Should get answer from health endpoint`() = testApplication {
        val response = client.get("/health")
        assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
        assertEquals("I'm alive", response.bodyAsText())
    }
```

This unit test works fine as long as the stream started in `Application.kt` does not use a KTable (at least a global KTable - I have not tested with a local KTable). If the stream uses a KTable, the unit test will never end as the stream will run indefinitely. This causes trouble in the GitLab pipeline where all the unit tests are executed.

Is there a "best practice" for testing the endpoints of a Kafka streams application built with Ktor? Especially, if the stream topology includes a KTable?

Comment: You can change a dispatcher for the code that starts a stream to not block the current thread https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-concurrency-and-coroutines.html#dispatcher-for-changing-threads. Please clarify your goal is to test a Kafka's stream or to test parts of your server independently of the stream?

Comment: My goal is to test parts of my server independently of the stream.

Comment: In that case, you can call your module with a stubbed Kafka's stream in the `testApplication` to prevent interruption of tests, e.g. `application { module(stubbedStream) }`.

Answer (score 1):

In **unit tests**, you should be using Kafka Streams's `TopologyTestDriver`.

If you want to run *integration* tests for an RPC layer over Kafka's Interactive Streams, it shouldn't matter if the stream is indefinitely running (that's the point of running Streams). The topology should be running in a background thread, and not block your tests or HTTP/RPC server.

Ideally, you have a way to inject a Topology or StreamsBuilder into the Application rather than both creating and starting in your main method.